# How do i broadcast a message to all clients via Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I have two Projects, an Asp.net WebAPI & a separate Single Page Web Application. My requirement is that when a form is submitted via the web application it is processed at the Web API. Once the Request has been handled successfully i want to broadcast a message to all the clients notifying them that a new request had been submitted.
How can I do it? Any help would be appreciated.
I looked into SignalR, but couldn't find an implementation for this requirement.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "looked into SignalR" but so many examples / tutorials of signalr are chat programs that do exactly that.

Comment: "SignalR" will be the best choice for you

Comment: I have done similar using "SignalR"  you need to look more into it ...Already cooked food is prohibited here :) you need to atleast try and then ask question regarding issue you face but you have to start something....

Comment: @confusedMind True, sorry about that, was kind of lost with this for a while. Simply took a step back and did some research. Signal R did work. I will post the answer, thanks for all the support. :)

Comment: i don't know if its help you - but you can see how its done on .net maui 

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-maui-good-bye-messagingcenter-welcome-weakreferencemanager/

Answer (score 1):

Pusher's got libraries you can use to handle anything notifications https://pusher.com/docs/libraries

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use signalR to cater your requirement. You can go thru this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is small use pusher "https://pusher.com/"

when you use that well It may be cheaper than you make And less resources.